# Execute php in different days

Tags: php

I'm trying to execute php in different days.

I'm getting data from select boxes using get_field

```
<?php if( $days): ?>
    <?php foreach( $days as $day ): ?>
        <?php echo $day; ?>, 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

So it gives me f.ex: Mon, Tue, Wed

I want to

```
echo "hello world";
```

be executed only in selected days, if not - do nothing

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array similar to this:

```php
$days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
```

You can just use another simple `if` statement:

```php
<?php if ($days): ?>
    <?php foreach ($days as $day): ?>
        <?php if ('Mon' === $day): ?>
            <?php echo $day; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you have multiple days that you want to test, you can use the `||` to perform an OR comparison:

```php
<?php if ($days): ?>
    <?php foreach ($days as $day): ?>
        <?php if ('Mon' === $day || 'Tue' === $day): ?>
            <?php echo $day; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And if you have a lot, or it makes more sense to you, you can use `in_array()` with an array of possible days:

```php
<?php if ($days): ?>
    <?php foreach ($days as $day): ?>
        <?php if (in_array($day, ['Mon', 'Tue'])): ?>
            <?php echo $day; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**edit**

The current short name for the day of the week can be retrieved used `date('D')`, so:

```php
$today = date('D');
```

I don't 100% know what logic you are going forward, but the above can be extended as such to test the loop and the current day of the week.

```php
<?php if ('Mon' === $day && $today === $day): ?>
```

Comment: I don't see get date in your answer. My point is when I check Mon and Fri, so         <?php echo $day; ?> will give me "Mon, Fri" and today's date is Mon or Fri - it makes echo "hello world". If we have f.ex. tuesday today - gives nothing.

Comment: I added an edit that hopefully addresses what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's Date() library like so:

```
$today = date('l');
```

Which returns the following on a Thursday:

> Thursday

Now with that you can use a simple switch case statement like so:

```
switch($today){
    case "Monday":
        monday();
        break;
    case "Tuesday":
        tuesday();
        break;
    and so on
    default:
        do nothing
        break;
}
```